# How do I send a POST request with params with WordPress REST API

Tags: php, login

I am new to WordPress and I'm trying to make a POST request to login a user. I want to be able to send "username" and "password" as params while making this call. How can I do so. This my code so far

```
        register_rest_route(
            'custom-plugin', '/login/(?P<username>\d/(?P<password>\d)',  
              array(
                'methods'  => 'POST',
                 'callback' => 'login_user',
         ));
```

Comment: please check this i hope solve your probelm https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290685/create-a-new-user-using-wp-rest-api-and-declare-meta-object

Comment: Sorry but my question was how to send params for a POST request, that answer was not clearing my doubt.

Comment: If you're trying to handle authentication for a mobile application or something, this is the least secure way to do it. See the docs on proper ways to authenticate with the REST API: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/ Also, you don't send requests _with_ the REST API, you send them _to_ the API, and the method you do it depends entirely on the context.